# Is block-wise locality pseudorandom generator standard assumption?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, computational-complexity-theory

To my best knowledge, the Goldreich's pseudorandom generator (PRG) with locality 5 has been considered as one of standard assumptions.

On the other hand, Lin and Tessaro (Crypto'17) provides a new notion, called the block-wise locality PRG. As I know, block-wise locality 2 PRG was broken, but block-wise locality 3 PRG still remains one of hard problems.

Then, in this situation, is still the block-wise locality 3 PRG considered as one of standard assumptions?